# In mysql why does M has to >= D for float type

Tags: mysql

I tried to define float(0,10) but it is not allowed. all my data in the table are less than 1.and float (10,10) would work. why do they have this rule for float type in mysql?

Comment: The first argument is the total length. i.e. `float(7,2)` would allow 90000.01 or 12300.01

Answer (score 4):

The first value is for total digits, the seconds for digits after the decimal point, sou you want `float(10,10)`, Reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/floating-point-types.html

Look here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0e8fb/2/0

Answer (score 2):

M stands for Mantisse, or the total number of significant digits in your number disregarding the decimal sign.
D stands for the decimals, i.e. the number of digits after the decimal sign.

Since the decimals are a true subset of all the digits in the mantisse, D must be smaller or equal than M

see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/floating-point-types.html

Comment: When linking to the docs, please try and link to the most current version, not the 5.0 version from over a decade ago.